# How do I colour genes in groups and have gene labels above the arrows in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R for the first time. I'm trying to use ggplot2 to make an arrow genome map and I am having trouble with a few of the details. 
 Here is a snippet of the data:

```
genome start end gene colour
A 11638 12786 fadA6 #04E762
A 12798 13454 fadE31 #04E762
A 13529 14341 fadE32 #04E762
A 14342 15541 fadE33 #FB5607
A 15627 17168 cyp142 #FB5607
```

And the code I currently have:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gggenes)
ggplot(REXAMPLE3, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = genome, fill = gene)) +
          geom_gene_arrow() +
          geom_gene_label(aes(label = gene)) +
          facet_wrap(~ genome, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
     scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")+
     theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: This is the output of the code]

- I need to colour the genes by function (e.g. green for side chain degradation) but I only know how to colour them individually with `gene1="colour"`. Is there a way to define the colour of each gene with a column in the dataset?
- Is there a way to make the labels go above the gene instead of within the arrow?
- Which aes do I change to make the genes look less 'cramped'?

Thank you in advance for any help. It's hard to know what to google when you're completely new to the program.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you could provide some example data that will expedite our ability to come up with a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for the tip - I have added a snippet of the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) To label your genes according to the color you want (and set in the column "color"), you can pass it in the argument `fill` of the `aes` and then use `scale_fill_identity()`.

2) To place the gene label above, you can set y to 1.05 in `geom_gene_label`, however, I noticed that the size of label is not consistent (cyp142 is smaller than others). So, you can replace `geom_gene_label` by `geom_text` and calculate the x position of each to place them in the middle of their corresponding arrows.

Altogether, you can write something like that:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gggenes)
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = start, xmax = end, y = genome, fill = colour)) +
  geom_gene_arrow() +
  geom_text(aes(x = end - ((end-start)/2), y = 1.1, label = gene)) +
  facet_wrap(~ genome, scales = "free", ncol = 1) +
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  scale_fill_identity()+
  xlab("")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Hi! Yes, it did. Thank you. The tip tp use geom_text was particularly helpful. Thankyou for your help!

Comment: Oh, of course. Thanks for linking this. I have voted and chose the answer :)